# Jar file not running on Java 6 or older

Tags: java

My windows computer has netbeans, and JDK 7 and JRE 7. I made a program and the jar file does not run on a MAC with only Java 6. Installing Java 7 on MAC is a hassle. Can someone help me run the file?

Stack Trace:

```
: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Have yu compiled your javacode with the option 'javac -source 1.6 ...'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is expected. If you want to compile with to target 6 with JDK 7, you should use following (assuming that you do not use Java 7 features):

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6
```

If you use Maven, go for:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you said in comment, you use Netbeans. I have no personal experience with it, but according [documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk7.html) you can change value of *Source/Binary Format* (to JDK 6 in this case).

Comment: Thank you for this! I kept putting -source 1.6 without the -target 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your source code targeted for example at a Java 6 runtime. Using Ant, it's achieved using the `target` attribute to the `javac` task. Using Maven, use the [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: How do I do this using Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your compilation targets to JDK 6 (or 5, or whatever is the lowest version you want to support).

In Netbeans, Go to the project properties (right-click on the project, select Properties_. Then in the dialog that appears, select "Sources" and change the "Source Level" to JDK 6.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot, in general, run a Java 7 file with the Java 6 runtime. You will have to either install Java 7, or rebuild the jar under Java 6.

Comment: That's not true. All jdk versions support generation of class files that are compatible with older JVMs.

Comment: If look at websites and in the compiler options you will find the 'source' and 'target' options. Even official the documantation say that is also possible.